# Confused about Egit's behavior

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

So this might just be me confused or doing something wrong. I am new to git so please bear that in mind when answering. Thanks!

So, the best way I can find to explain my "problem" is to describe the scenario. I have just reinstalled eclipse and egit because I was so frustrated and this is still happening. I would start a brand new project, and then I'd to go team>share project> git, and I would create a new repository under my user/git/ folder. I would instantiate the local repo with an initial commit through the git staging window, adding all files in "unstaged changes" into "staged changes" then in the description call it "commit 0001" then hit commit. After this I would go into my project create the `Main.cs` class and then add the `main(String[] args)` method with just a simple `System.out.println("Commit 0002");` call. I would then repeat the previous commit process except now calling this commit "commit 0002". This is where the problem comes in. I go to view the previous commits in the commit history view and it does not show "commit 0001", just "commit 0002". And this continues. If I change something then commit it under "Commit 0003", commit 0002 is "forgotten" and JUST commit 0003 is shown.

I Hope I described the scenario okay. If it is confusing please tell me! Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually creating new commits? One explanation could be that you accidentally toggled the 'amend' behavior and all your commits are therefore just changes to your original 0001 commit. Should be easy to check via EGit's 'Git Reflog View'...

Comment: Where would you find that at?

Comment: Press Ctrl+3 (Quick Access), type ahead ('Git Reflog'), and it should appear in the 'Views' section...

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check **in command line** that:

- you are actually in a branch (`cd /your/repo; git branch -avv`)
- you have multiple commits (`cd /your/repo; git log --graph --oneline --all`)

With EGit, as described in "[Important settings in the history view](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#historyview_settings) ":

- make sure you don't have any filter in place
- that you show all branches

[image: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/images/xhistoryview_toolbar10.png.pagespeed.ic.6KneC-xaic.png]